# I can't download packages in pycharm CE

Tags: python, numpy, installation, package, pycharm

I'm trying to download numpy in Pycharm but it keep saying invalid syntax:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 2, in <module>
    import traceback
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tokenize.py", line 394
    r    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm currently using Python 3.10. I have download Python 3.12 and can install packages just fine, but now I want to use tensorflow and I can't download it on 3.12.
I have tried to use terminal to download it, but it's just the same, I even used the way that Jetbrains show in their Documentation (https://jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/package-installation-issues.html#results) but I still can't fix it. Please help me.

Comment: We have no idea on what you did. Which version you downloaded? How did you intalled it? How did you test it? These are all relevant questions. Note: I recommend you to use miniconda (or anaconda) and installa python and package from there, and always on some virtual environment, so you can test different versions and still being able to run old code (all packages, also tensorflow break)

Comment: I tried numpy ver 1.21. I use the Python package tab in Pycharm to install at first, and a window called Install numpy fail appear. I tried using terminal using the guide of this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/package-installation-issues.html#terminal, and this still appear:     
r    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I have tried this method on python 3.12 and I can install them just fine (except tensorflow)
When I access my pycharmproject that use python 3.10, a window called Packaging Operation failed also appear invalid syntax

Comment: Tensorflow is not yet available for python 3.12. Use python 3.11 or 3.10.